# как к string конкатенировать char(Символ)?

Tags: c++, строки, char

```
string CBattlePlayer::printAquatory()
{
    string str = " Ваш акваторий\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Акваторий Врага\n\n   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10\t\t\t\t\t   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10\n";
    string buf;
    char s = 'A';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        str += s + " ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {

            str += m_Aqua.m_Cells[i][j].PrintOwn();
        }
        str += "\t\t\t\t";
        str += s + " ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            str += m_pAnotherPlayer->m_Aqua.m_Cells[i][j].PrintForeign();
        }

        str += "\n";
        s++;
    }

    return str;
}
```

char s служит для обозначения букв слева, to_string(),string() и обычное прибавление не работает. В первом случае выводится код символа, 2 не будет работать из-за того, что он работает только с массивом символов, а в 3 случае выводится в консоли ols\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\xutility
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: По твоему это "обычное прибавление" `str += s + " ";`?

Comment: Я только новичок, и не знал, что так нельзя. Harry уже объяснил, спасибо вам всем за помощь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да просто прибавить. [Типа](https://ideone.com/bQA2wz),

```
string s = "Hello, ";
s += 'A';
```

Comment: да, но у меня выводит в консоли: C\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\xutility. Уже пробовал так делать). Щас изменю вопрос для лучшего понимания

Comment: изменил, просто думал как лучше сформулировать

Comment: У вас как минимум неверно `str += s + " ";` — вы не прибавляете отдельно `char` и пробел, а прибавляете строку по странному адресу... `(str += s) += " ";` — вот так будет лучше. Или просто `str += s; str += " ";`

Comment: Благодарю, не знал, что так нельзя

Comment: пытался понять, почему это так нельзя складывать. аж задумался о том, что я плюсы не понимаю... ну кто char переменную называет именем s... а тут ещё @Harry посластил своим ответом, использовав `string s`. так до седых волос довести можно:)

Comment: Извините, это я для примера так назвал)